# Launch Image for ios 8 in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

There is an xib file for launch image in Xcode named `LaunchScreen.xib`. can we attach some code files (.h and .m) to customize the splash?

[image]

Comment: You can write code in AppDelegate class (not use .xib) this is your choice, if you want to customize your splash view....

Comment: yes this thing I already know. I was thinking if new xcode has given some efficient way.

Comment: you can't add `.m`, `.h` or `.swift` file for the lunch screen; I mean you can add, but it won't be executed during lunch. your very first enter point is still in the _AppDelegate_ file's `–application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The launch image (or in this case the launch xib) is shown before any code can be executed. The launch image is replaced with your first view when the launching is finished. At this time is the first moment you can execute code to change the contents of the screen.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to add some animated splash. Now I need to make my own view then have to show it for some time.

Comment: @dasdom please have a look at my post and I have made changes to splash screen and it worked. So at end we can customise it at our will.

Comment: You can customize the splash screen, but you can not for example run animation in the launch screen, because you cannot run code.

Comment: @dasdom, you can execute code already _inside_ the `–application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you don't need to wait for that method has returned.

Comment: @holex But this is only a fraction of the time the launch image is shown. And you cannot update the launch view in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: @dasdom, no, of course not, I'm not saying updating _that_ launch screen, I just said that you are able to run code before the launch finished – in you answer you have made a tiny statement about it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use the xib editing tools to design it. You cannot use any code as the xib is used before any code is actually run.